# How can I create an UPDATE statement from a large XML data type?

Tags: sql-server

I am working with two databases that are not accessible at the same time. One of the standard methods of dealing with this I've seen on here is to create dynamic sql for loading one from the other.

I created a stored procedure that would drop update statements from an existing database. My issue is what happens when the XML is too large to be held in a VARCHAR(max).

Here is a relevant snippet from my attempt where field2 is actually of an XML data type:

```
DECLARE @field1Col VARCHAR(50)
DECLARE @field2Col VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE @vsSQL VARCHAR(max)
DECLARE curUpdates CURSOR FOR
-- field 1 is varchar(50), not null
-- field 2 is XML(.), null
SELECT
       t.field1
      ,REPLACE(CAST(t.[field2] AS VARCHAR(max)), '''', '''''') 
  FROM
       myTable t
 WHERE
       t.criteria = 0
OPEN curUpdates
FETCH NEXT FROM curUpdates INTO @field1Col, @field2Col
WHILE @@FETCH_STATUS = 0 
BEGIN
    SET @vsSQL = 'UPDATE dbo.myTable SET [field1] = ''' + @field1Col+ ''' WHERE [field2] = ''' + @field2Col + ''''      
    INSERT INTO @tmp ( SQLText ) VALUES ( @vsSQL )
    FETCH NEXT FROM curUpdates INTO @field1Col, @field2Col
END
CLOSE curUpdates
DEALLOCATE curUpdates

SET NOCOUNT OFF;
SELECT * FROM @tmp
```

The issue I have is that even using VARCHAR(max), the XML will sometimes overrun the size. The end product just stops when it reaches the so many characters (the max size of a VARCHAR?).

Is there another approach for working with large XML (splitting into chunks, avoid casting, etc.) where I can build a string of update statements from it?

Comment: Don't get this... Is there any reason to convert the existing XML to a string type? Why?

Comment: As stated in the question, I am trying to build UPDATE statements from the XML. I am not married to working with it as a string, but the string affords me the ability to (1) escape any single quotes found in the XML, which would prevent a normal UPDATE statement from working, and (2) allows for straightforward string concatenation as seen in the line with the SET command.

Comment: Your xml is over 2GB in size?

Comment: Don't use string concatenation (aka sql injection). Use sp_executesql and use parameters instead if you can

Comment: This is a big red flag to me that the design of this process is less than ideal. Dynamic sql being generated by columns and values being passed in is generally a sign of things gone wrong.

Comment: No, the XML isn't 2GB in size. However the output cuts off after character 43,680 each time.

Comment: @JoePhilllips, won't sp_executesql execute the sql I am building? I actually don't want to execute the UPDATE statements on the same database that I am unloading from. The UPDATE statements that are built will have to be taken over to another database and there is a firewall in between.

Comment: @SeanLange At this point I am open to any helpful suggestions. Can you suggest a better method to update two databases that are not accessible at the same time?

Comment: What do you mean by "updating two databases that are not accessible at the same time"? I don't understand what you are trying to do here.

Comment: @SeanLange When I am on database A, I do not have access to database B. I'd like to (one time run) update a few tables in database B to the values present in a mirror table in database A, so I am unloading from A and pushing the unload file through a firewall into the environment that B resides on, and executing.

Comment: You can use linked databases.. you could also just write a program that stores a sql string and isn't limited to varchar size

Comment: @BrianCross You said the output cuts off? Are you talking about in SSMS? There is a setting to increase it. I'm pretty sure you can make that up to 2GB. This question is really confusing.

Answer (score 0):

> I do not have access to database B. I'd like to (one time run) update
>   a few tables in database B

The *one time run* could point to something like this:

```
CREATE DATABASE MyOneTimeRun;
GO

USE MyOneTimeRun;
GO

SELECT * INTO MyCopy FROM YourDatabase.dbo.YourTable;
GO

BACKUP DATABASE [MyOneTimeRun] TO  DISK = N'C:\Path\MyOneTimeRun.bak' WITH NOFORMAT, NOINIT
               ,NAME = N'MyOneTimeRun-Copy of MyTable'
               ,SKIP, NOREWIND, NOUNLOAD,  STATS = 10
GO
USE master;
GO
EXEC msdb.dbo.sp_delete_database_backuphistory @database_name = N'MyOneTimeRun'
GO
USE [master]
GO
ALTER DATABASE [MyOneTimeRun] SET  SINGLE_USER WITH ROLLBACK IMMEDIATE
GO
USE [master]
GO
DROP DATABASE [MyOneTimeRun]
GO
```

Now you have a BAK-file with the content you need which you can restore on your other server.

There you use the appropriate scripts to shuffle your data typesafe and clean from the copy into your target.